# Calculating estimated location from distance to known locations

Tags: leaflet, geospatial

I am trying to see if there is a plugin or Node library that will be able to estimate a lat/long based on an array of distances from known locations. Attached image shows three circles which are radius from known location. I would like to take this information and estimate a location from the combination of information. Originally I was thinking of just showing the intersect of the circles, but that does not cover cases where the circles do not intersect.[image]